# Confused with dynamic memory allocation C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm a little confused about dynamic memory allocation and I was hoping someone could help clear it up for me.

So say we have a program:

```
int length = 0;

cout << "Enter the size of the array" << endl;
cin >> length;
cin.ignore();

int numbers[length];
```

> Wouldn't this still be dynamic memory allocation
>   since the array size is being defined at runtime
>   after the user enters in the specified length?

vs using:

```
int numQuestions = 0;

cout << "How many questions would you like to add?" << endl;
cin >> numQuestions;
cin.ignore();

Question *newQuestions = new Question[numQuestions];
```

Comment: The first example is not standard C++, which does not have variable-length arrays, as such your question is moot. You're using a compiler extension.

Comment: Arrays with Runtime Bound were proposed into C++14 in n3639 but voted out so it will probably take some time until someone resurrects that proposal.

Comment: @ÖöTiib - I doubt it will be resurrected.  VLAs were optional in C99 and formally removed from the C standard in 2011 - and the reasons were based on assessed disadvantages in C. That weakened any justification based on C compatibility.  Furthermore, most of the down-sides of VLAs for C are also applicable to C++.  The feature also doesn't play too well with the C++ object model (constructors, destructors, etc) and C++ also provides alternatives (like standard containers) that are considered preferable to using any raw array construct in C++.

Answer (score 1):

**What's the difference?** Dynamic memory is allocated on the heap, but arrays are allocated on the stack. Because the memory for `int numbers[length]` is allocated on the stack, it's not considered dynamic memory allocation. **More importantly, you can't return a pointer to an array allocated this way, because that array is a local variable that gets destroyed when the function exits.**

That's the purpose of dynamic allocation - dynamic allocation allows memory to stick around for as long as you need it, and it won't go away until `delete` is called on the pointer to the memory.

Also, it should be noted that declaring an array with a size determined at run-time is non-standard C++ that's supported by some compilers as an extension.

**So what's best practice?** Using raw pointers is the old way of doing stuff. It's error-prone because you might forget to delete the memory, or if there's an exception, the code to delete the memory might get bypassed. This causes a memory leak.

If you use `std::vector` instead, you get the following benefits:

- You can determine the size at run-time,
- You can return a `vector` from a function,
- The memory allocated by the vector *automatically* gets deleted, so there won't be a memory leak.

**How do I use `std::vector`**?

It's pretty simple! Just replace

```
int numbers[length];
```

with

```
std::vector<int> numbers(length);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Just what I needed, thank you.